# Cannot do a simple function using call by value method in C

Tags: c, factorial, pass-by-value, unsigned-integer, function-definition

I am trying to test this method (call by value) i recently learned, but for unkown reasons for me, the code isn't working, can someone explain me why? (sorry for the mess by the way)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fact(int i);


int main() {
   int x;

   scanf("%d", x);
   //function called:

   fact(x);

   printf("value of x! = %d", x);

   return 0;
}


//factorial definition:
void fact(int i){
   int j=0;
   for(i=1; j>1; j--){
      i= i * j;
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `fact` to do? You never return a value, so the values of `i` and `j` are lost when the function exits. Also, you immediately return during the first iteration of the loop in `fact`, which I doubt is the intended behavior.

Comment: If your compiler lets you get away with such obvious errors as `scanf("%d", x);` you should figure out how to enable its warnings and errors so it can protect you.  A suitably configured compiler would never build code like that at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think i should return 'i' variable.

Comment: You can't use i as both the value you're multiplying up and the limit for the j loop. I suggest you make another variable to be the value you're computing and return that, not i. (It might also be worth considering returning a long instead of an int, as factorials get big quickly.)

Comment: john Zwink, thanks for pointing me that, that was a stupid error indeed.

Comment: user495758 To be clear `scanf("%d", x);` is not _the_ error.  Not compiling will all warnings enabled is the error.  We all make otherwise errors.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a call to a function by value to make calculations with the passed argument then to get the result of the calculations in the caller the function must return a value. That is its return type should not be `void`.

The definition of the function `fact` does not make sense. In the for loop the parameter `i` is reassigned to `1`. The loop itself never iterates because another variable `j` is set to `0`. So it can not be greater than `1`.

```
int j=0;
for(i=1; j>1; j--){
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
//factorial definition:
unsigned long long int fact( unsigned int i )
{
    unsigned long long int f = 1;

    while ( i > 1 ) f *= i--;

    return f;
}
```

The factorial is defined for unsigned natural integers.

In main you need to declare a variable of the type unsigned int like

```
unsigned int x;
```

This call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", x);
```

is incorrect. The function needs to accept its integer argument by reference to change it.

```
scanf( "%u", &x );
```

To get the result of the function `fact` you have to introduce one more variable

```
unsigned long long int result = fact( x );
```

And to output it you should write

```
printf( "value of %u! = %llu\n", x, result );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long int fact( unsigned int );

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int x;

    scanf( "%u", &x );

    unsigned long long int result = fact( x );

    printf( "value of %u! = %llu\n", x, result );

    return 0;
}

//factorial definition:
unsigned long long int fact( unsigned int i )
{
    unsigned long long int f = 1;

    while ( i > 1 ) f *= i--;

    return f;
}
```

If to enter the number `20` then the function output will be

```
value of 20! = 2432902008176640000
```

Pay attention to that `20` is the maximum number the factorial of which can be stored in an object of the type `unsigned long long int`.

If you want that the function accepted its argument by reference and returned the result in the argument then you have to declare the variable `x` as having the type unsigned long long int.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fact( unsigned long long int * );

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned long long int x;

    scanf( "%llu", &x );

    printf( "value of %llu! = ", x );
    fact( &x );
    printf( "%llu\n", x );

    return 0;
}

//factorial definition:
void fact( unsigned long long int *x )
{
    unsigned long long int f = 1;

    while ( *x > 1 ) f *= ( *x )--;

    *x = f;
}
```

If to enter `20` then the program output will be the same as shown above.

```
value of 20! = 2432902008176640000
```

Comment: Thanks very much vlad! Really helpfull men!

Answer (score 1):

Scanf takes a pointer to the variable, to return something from a void function you must call it by reference with a pointer to the return variable and not by its value.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I will use the reference method.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem 1:

```
scanf("%d", x);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

The `&` is very important.

---

## Problem 2

In function `fact`, you start `j` at `0`:

```
int j=0;
```

Your loop only runs while `j>1`:

```
for(i=1; j>1; j--){
```

Tell me:  When is `0` ***ever*** `>1`??
Your loop will never run.

---

## Problem 3:

You expect that calling `fact(x);` will change the value of `x`.
In C, a function **cannot** change one of its arguments; arguments are passed "by-copy".

If you wish to change an object (variable) in the caller, you must pass a *pointer* to it:

```
void fact(int* i);

[...]
//function called:
fact(&x);
[...]


//factorial definition:
void fact(int* i){
   int j=0;
   for(*i=1; j>1; j--){
      *i= *i * j;
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Because `scanf()` is called by value, which is in the question title :)

Comment: problem 3 return is inside the for loop

Comment: Hmmm, suggest moving `return` outside of loop.

Comment: In reference to problem 2, i was trying to initialize the variable, because its a local one, didnt think it could create a problem..

Comment: @Simson:  That isn't really a problem, because you never get into the loop in the first place (see Problem 2)

Comment: Functions cannot change their arguments. Functions can change their parameters. The argument is the expression in the list in the function call (C 2018 3.3). The parameter is the object declared in the function definition that acquires a value when the function starts (3.16). Those parameters are objects just as if they had been declared at the start of the function body, and functions can change them.